# I want to sum many value from a table based on the type

Tags: mysql

I want to sum the Amount depend on the Type field.

Example: type:water sum of all the Amount related to water.

And i want to put the in a table depend on the year.
water=>sum of Amount =>year:2017

table:

-------
year  |  Type  |  Amount
2017  |  water |  200
2018  |  water |  300

My query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount_expenses_table), year(Date_expenses_table) FROM 
bacci.expenses_table WHERE year(Date_expenses_table)='2017'and 
Type_expenses_table = 'water' GROUP BY monthname(date_expenses_table);
```

I want to get not only water many things and put the result in vb.net, so i thing to make a table for this and put the sum in the table like above

[image]

Comment: Congrats on identifying what you want. Now, have you tried writing any code at all, or do you just expect the internet to do it all for you?

Comment: I don't see an attempt at the `SQL`  -- Show us what you have tried and we'll gladly show your shortcomings!

Comment: sorry guys i updated my question

Comment: show your code which you tried.

Comment: are the expenses types fixed or could there be more added in future?

Comment: @SEarle1986 it can be added in the future, the table now is for testing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will meet your requirement:

```
SELECT year(Date_expenses_table) , Type_expenses_table, SUM(Amount_expenses_table) FROM 
bacci.expenses_table WHERE year(Date_expenses_table)='2017' GROUP BY year(Date_expenses_table) , Type_expenses_table;
```